# How to configure ARC compiler in meson build

Tags: meson-build

I'm transferring our build system from Make to meson/ninja.
when trying to set up a cross-file for ARC, executing the meson setup:

```
meson setup --buildtype PATH/TO/BUILD/DIR debug --cross-file PATH/TO/FILE
```

i receive an error:

> meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['/efs/data/public/synopsis/ARC-2018.06/MetaWare/arc/bin/ccac']]

here's my cross file:

```
[binaries]
c = '/efs/data/public/synopsis/ARC-2018.06/MetaWare/arc/bin/ccac'
cpp = '/efs/data/public/synopsis/ARC-2018.06/MetaWare/arc/bin/ccac'
ar = '/efs/data/public/synopsis/ARC-2018.06/MetaWare/arc/bin/ccac'

[host_machine]
system = 'linux'
cpu_family = 'arc'
cpu = 'hs36'
endian = 'little'
```

Any ideas ? 
in the meson documentation, it appears as arc architecture is supported.
https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-tables.html

**Update:**

gnu's  ARC compiler is supported.

**Solved:**

after reaching meson's developers mailing list, 
we are adding implementation for synopsis's proprietary compiler in meson's source and will commit the changes to meson's project.

Comment: what's the version of meson you're using? According to https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/pull/4234 arc is supposed to be supported from 0.49

Comment: i'm using 0.50.0, it seems the gnu arc compiler is supported, but not the synopsis proprietary one.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **Compiler ids** table - there is no ARC compiler, and I checked meson sources in meson/mesonbuild/compilers and didn't find ccac. So, there is no support for ARC compiler in meson. You can contact Synopsys about plans for integration, the best contact there I know for this is [Alexey Brodkin](https://github.com/abrodkin).